# How can I lookup for the MX records corresponding to a particular domain name in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

E.g. 
I have a address say: mycompany.com
& there are MX records for this address as:
server1.mycompany.com
server2.mycompany.com
server2.mycompany.com

Now,there's a web serivce which is hosted on all 3 of above servers for redundancy or fallback.
So,before calling the web service from my iPhone app,I want to do lookup for mycompany.com for MX records & invoke the web service on one of the 3 servers returned by MX records.
Which API/Class or framework of iPhone I need to use?
Is it possible with CFHost?

Comment: Can I use resolv.h & nameser.h together? or does dns.h provides capabilities for querying MX records for a domain?

Comment: i am able to get IP records against a domain name, but still looking to get other DNS records like cname, mx etc... can't figure it out or find anywhere.. if you get a solution to this do tell me